# Remove empty properties from object in list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have the following code:

```
var result = dataService.ItemGeneralSearch_v1("ddd", value[0], value[0]);

var newList = result.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperties()
                  .Select(p => p.GetValue(x, null))
                  .Any(p => p != null)).ToList();
```

The result contains a List with ItemGeneral-object.

ItemGeneral

```
public class ItemGeneral
{
    public string ITEM_NO { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_STATE { get; set; }
    public string ITEM_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRODNAME_NO { get; set; }
    public string PRODNAME_NO2 { get; set; }
}
```

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is to filter out all the properties that has a null-value in the ItemGeneral-objects. But it doesn't work with the code above.

I want to return a filtered list with the objects containing only the properties with a value. So no properties with null-values.

Comment: What do you mean remove properties? Do you want to remove all those `ItemGeneral` objects which have at least one property null?

Comment: What do you mean "filter out all the properties"?

Comment: I want to return a filtered list with the objects containing only the properties with a value. So no properties with null-values.

Comment: `But It don't work with the code above.` What do you want the code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: mjwills: Look at my question.

Comment: Do you mean that if you have an item wit the `ITEM_NAME` null then it will just not appear?

Comment: @GiladGreen: I don't know how I can be more clear: If any of the objects in the list contains a null value, I want to remove this property and value, so I only have a list with objects that does NOT contain properties with null-values.

Comment: @Bryan - and still result with a list of `ItemGeneral`? If so then the answer is - you cant. That is why you need to be more clear

Comment: @GiladGreen: Yes, exactly. Why can't I do this?

Comment: @Bryan You can do it, but not return `ItemGeneral`.  You can instead return an anonymous type.  If you return `ItemGeneral`, the properties will still be there but with `null` as their values.

Comment: @Tom: Can you give me a example how I could do It with an anonymous type?

Comment: Let's say `result` contains three `ItemGeneral` objects. The first two of them have all six properties set to "a". The third one has only `ITEM_NO` set to "a" and everything else is null. How many items do you expect to have returned? 2? 3? 12? 13? And what type do you expect to assign to `newList`?

Comment: @Bryan Well, you could use a dynamic.  Check if the property is not null, if so, add a property with the value to the dynamic object, repeat for each property, and then return.  You need to explain why you need to do this though...

Comment: @mjwills: All thre objects should be returned, but the third object would only contain the ITEM_NO propertie because It has a value and are not null.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this if you want to stay with your custom type. Reason is that if you define a type with some properties then when initializing that type the properties are there, whether you assign to them a value or not.

However using anonymous types and `dynamic` you can:

```
var result = data.Select(item => {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var x = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var p in item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetValue(item) != null))
            x[p.Name] = p.GetValue(item, null);
        return expando;
    }).ToList();
```